# Http Post in android is not responding. The code is correct

Tags: java, android, xml, http, post

I'm trying to make an application in android which can post some data to a php server on clicking a button. On clicking the button though, there is no reaction from the app. The log doesn't show any attempt to connect.

### MainActivity.java

```java
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new httpier().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    private class httpier extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Double> {

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://httptestingjawzf.host56.com/androidpost.php");

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vehicleId", "abc"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", "abc"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", "abc"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());



            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (NullPointerException n) {

            }
        return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

### Activity_Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.trial.jawzf.myapplication" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the log when i click the button:

```
02-03 13:52:59.034  29911-29911/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 763K, 18% free 12555K/15156K, paused 6ms+4ms, total 62ms
02-03 13:52:59.049  29911-29920/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ FinalizerDaemon calls detatch()
02-03 13:52:59.049  29911-29920/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ FinalizerDaemon calls detatch()
02-03 13:52:59.049  29911-29920/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ FinalizerDaemon calls detatch()
02-03 13:52:59.049  29911-29920/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ FinalizerDaemon calls detatch()
02-03 13:52:59.049  29911-29920/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ FinalizerDaemon calls detatch()
02-03 13:52:59.049  29911-29920/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ FinalizerDaemon calls detatch()
02-03 13:52:59.049  29911-29920/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ FinalizerDaemon calls detatch()
02-03 13:52:59.049  29911-29920/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ FinalizerDaemon calls detatch()
02-03 13:52:59.049  29911-29920/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ FinalizerDaemon calls detatch()
02-03 13:52:59.049  29911-29920/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ FinalizerDaemon calls detatch()
02-03 13:53:28.769  29911-29911/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/HWUI﹕ EGLImpl-HWUI Protected EGL context created
02-03 13:53:43.039  29911-29911/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
02-03 13:53:52.469    1443-1458/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:48 height:48 bitmap id is 180
02-03 13:53:52.469    1443-1458/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 181
02-03 13:53:52.474    1443-1458/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:42 height:126 bitmap id is 182
02-03 13:53:52.474    1443-1458/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:18 height:18 bitmap id is 183
02-03 13:53:52.474    1443-1459/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:18 height:18 bitmap id is 184
02-03 13:53:52.474    1443-1458/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:18 height:18 bitmap id is 185
02-03 13:53:52.474    1443-1459/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 186
02-03 13:53:52.479    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ dvmPauseGc(AppLaunch) called - cookie=0x9c28 (f=0x1)
02-03 13:53:52.484    1443-1460/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 187
02-03 13:53:52.484    1443-1462/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 188
02-03 13:53:52.484    1443-1464/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 189
02-03 13:53:52.484    1443-1456/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 190
02-03 13:53:52.484    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
02-03 13:53:52.494    1443-1461/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 191
02-03 13:53:52.504    1443-1463/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 192
02-03 13:53:52.534    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
02-03 13:53:52.534    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11341: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
02-03 13:53:52.534    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
02-03 13:53:52.534    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
02-03 13:53:52.534    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11347: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
02-03 13:53:52.534    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
02-03 13:53:52.534    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
02-03 13:53:52.534    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9035: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
02-03 13:53:52.534    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
02-03 13:53:52.539    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-03 13:53:52.539    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 364: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-03 13:53:52.539    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-03 13:53:52.539    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-03 13:53:52.539    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 386: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-03 13:53:52.539    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-03 13:53:52.549    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 193
02-03 13:53:52.604    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/﹕ PLATFORM VERSION : JB-MR-2
02-03 13:53:52.619    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/HWUI﹕ EGLImpl-HWUI Protected EGL context created
02-03 13:53:52.659    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-03 13:53:52.709    1443-1443/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication E/dalvikvm﹕ dvmResumeGc(0x9c28, 0) called (f=0x1)
02-03 13:53:55.104    1443-1480/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ Thread-29082(ApacheHTTPLog):Reading from variable values from setDefaultValuesToVariables
02-03 13:53:55.109    1443-1480/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ Thread-29082(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
02-03 13:53:55.109    1443-1480/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication I/System.out﹕ Thread-29082(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
02-03 14:38:03.379  14577-14779/com.trial.jawzf.myapplication D/Http Post Response:﹕ org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@42678660
```

This is the php file I'm using:

```
<?php 
        include 'database.php';
       $vID   = $_POST['vehicleId'];
       $latitude=$_POST['latitude'];
       $longitude=$_POST['longitude'];
       $userid = $_POST['uid'];

       $sqlline = " INSERT INTO $userid VALUES ('$vID','$latitude','$longitude')";
       $result=mysql_query($sqlline);



 ?>
```

Is this php file correct?

Comment: what you mean `there is no reaction from the app` ???

Comment: I have posted the log when i run the app...the program doesn't respond after the last line.. the button is click able... but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure this code does not work? I think it successfully sends data to server and silently finish his work because you don't process the response.

Comment: if this code is working it is supposed to show something in logcat just as i saw in other posts on the internet.. but it doesn't show anything.. the logs stop at the last line i've posted

Comment: `just as i saw in other posts`. You will see that in other posts the catch blocks contain at least the line `e.printStackTrace()`. An often also a `Log.d().`. So start adding them. Then also add more Log.d()'s in doInBackground to follow the flow.

Comment: `how do i process the response?`. Just as you can see in other posts. ;-). response.toString() is not the way.

Comment: i added a Log.d and i have attached the new logcat response.. is the last line above normal? 
"Http Post Response:﹕ org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@42678660"

Comment: `is the last line above normal?`. I already told you that that was not the way to go. About your php script: The script is not echo()ing anything. You should just firsdt omit the sql and only echo the received parameters. Check the response for the echo()'s. The wholoe script misses error checking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the following code:

```
final TextView hello=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://httptestingjawzf.host56.com/androidpost.php");

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vehicleId", "abc"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", "abc"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", "abc"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

                if (resEntity != null) {

                    String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                    Log.v("TAG", "Response: " +  responseStr);
                }






            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (NullPointerException n) {

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
```

using the getEntity() function!!